# using jquery's '.on' to target, add, and remove classes

Tags: jquery

I have what you'll probably think is a very simple jQuery question. (I'm very new to this.)

I have a menu made up of a bunch of `<h2>`s, and I'd like each menu item to move to one side when clicked, returning to its original position when a *different* menu item is clicked. I'm doing this with 'animate' in jQuery. I thought I could do this by adding an ".active" class and using .not('.active') in my jQuery selector so that if the user clicks on the menu item repeatedly it won't just keep moving across the screen; however, it's not working correctly, and I think that's because changing classes aren't taken into account when I use `$(document).ready`. So I'm trying to use `.on` instead, but I'm floundering in the terminology. I wanted to use it with `.not,` but I read on this site that that can't be done; so I switched things up and tried to create an ".*in*active" class -- but that's not working for me either.

Original `$(document).ready` code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-item').not('.active').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.active').animate({left: '-=120px'}, '1000');
        $(this).siblings('.active').removeClass('active'); 
        $(this).animate({left: '+=120px'}, '1000');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Attempt at using `.not`:

```
$('.menu-item .inactive').on('click', function(event) {
        $(this).siblings.not('.inactive').animate({left: '-=120px'}, '1000');
        $(this).siblings.not('.inactive').addClass('inactive'); 
        $(this).animate({left: '+=120px'}, '1000');
        $(this).removeClass('inactive');
});
```

Any ideas on why the `.not` version isn't working, or (if possible) how I can get this thing to work just using `$(document).ready`?

Comment: remove the quote in animate duration animate({left: '-=120px'}, 1000) and check and siblings().not if not working give your html code to check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work because `$('.menu-item').not('.active')` will filter the elements when the event registration happens, then I don't think any of the menu-items has the class active assigned to it.

The solution you should have is

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-item:not(.active)', function(){
    //do
})
```